# Objects from query results are working with dot notation but throwing not callable with .get

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi, pydantic

```py
sample_object = db.fetch_one(sample_query) # Object from db query result
print(sample_object.key) #working when called`
#does not work when 
print(sample_object.get("key"))
```

It's working in version python 3.9.6 but not from 3.10.4

Comment: There is no version 3.10.01 of Python

Comment: Did you mean to use `getattr(sample_object, 'key')`? Otherwise it'll depend on what type of methods `sample_object` implements - i.e. what database library / ORM you're using to fetch it. It would also be helpful if you include the actual code you're using (I doubt that `fatch_one` is a valid method name), just to make sure that the question shows the whole picture.

Comment: Are you using a popular ORM for your FastAPI project? or you're using a self-written ORM?

Comment: yes I'm using orm

Comment: Do you use sqlalchemy?

Comment: yes I do use sqlalchemy

Answer (score 0):

Based on [**`fetchone()`** <sup>[sqlalchemy-docs]</sup>](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Result.fetchone), it returns:

> Fetch one row.
> When all rows are exhausted, returns None.

And the `fetchone()` method is a method of [`Row`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Row) object in sqlalchemy ORM which:

> Represent a single result row.
> The Row object represents a row of a database result. It is typically associated in the 1.x series of SQLAlchemy with the CursorResult object, however is also used by the ORM for **tuple-like** results as of SQLAlchemy 1.4.

So with more focus on `Row` object in sqlalchemy you can find out it's not an object like `dict` python built-in type and you can't use `.get()` method.

Comment: same code working with different env based packages 3.9.6